# C# WinForms App "DataRepeater.RemoveAt(index);" - Method is not reading index correctly in for loop

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to empty my DataRepeater on my C# WinForm App.

When the button is clicked, it checks whether the number of items displayed is not null. As a result, a for loop calls the .RemoveAt method every index.

I keep getting the OutOfRange Exception

```
    int countResults;

    private void btnGo_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (countResults != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < countResults; i++)
            {
                if (i >= countResults)
                {
                    break;
                }
                dataRepeater1.RemoveAt(i);                    
            }
        }

        // Assign item count value
        countResults = dataRepeater1.ItemCount;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the count before you loop. You shouldn't need the `if` statement either.

```
int countResults;

private void btnGo_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Assign item count value
    countResults = dataRepeater1.ItemCount;

    if (countResults != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < countResults; i++)
        {
            dataRepeater1.RemoveAt(i);                    
        }
    }        
}
```